# checking path in upload file and display

Tags: php

I have 2 php files that display uploaded picture.
first is form_upload.php

```
<html>
<head><title>File Upload</title></head>
<body>
<ol>
    <li>Enter the file name of the product picture you want to upload or the the browse button to navigate to the picture file</li>
    <li>when the path to the picture file shpws in the text field, click the upload picture</li>
</ol>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadFile.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="500000"/>
<input type="file" name="pix" size="60"/>
<p><input type='submit' name="Upload" value="Upload picture"/></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

second is uploadedFile.php

```
<?php

if(!isset($_POST['Upload']))
{
    include("form_upload.php");
}
else
{
    if($_FILES['pix']['tmp_name']=="") //check wether the file is larger than 2mb or not
    {
        echo "file did not successfully upload. Check the file size. File must be less than 500K";
        include("form_upload.php");
        exit();
    }
    if(!preg_match("/image\/jpeg/",$_FILES['pix']['type']))
    {
        echo "only jpg files are allowed. Please try another file";
        include("form_upload.php");
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        $destination='C:\xampp\htdocs\test\hinh\ '.$_FILES['pix']['name'];
        $temp_file=$_FILES['pix']['tmp_name'];
            move_uploaded_file($temp_file,$destination);
        echo "<p>the file has successfully uploaded :{$_FILES['pix']['name']} {$_FILES['pix']['type']} ({$_FILES['pix']['size']}) </p>";
        echo "<img src='C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\hinh\\{$_FILES['pix']['name']}' alt='picture'><br/>";
        echo "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\hinh\\{$_FILES['pix']['name']}";

    }
}
?>
```

I can not display the image after uploading. I checked the path is correct. But when i put 
it in  tag it doesn't display the picture here is my syntax:

```
echo "<img src='C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\hinh\\{$_FILES['pix']['name']}' alt='picture'><br/>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not reference the file with a filesystem path on drive "C". You should instead use a HTTP link, preferredly a relative link, like so:

```
echo "<img src='/path/to/upload/{$_FILES['pix']['name']}' alt='picture'><br/>";
```

I don't know how that path is named on your webserver. You have to find out yourself what is right. I guess it might be `/test/hinh/`.